# Enabling Cortana channel in Azure Bot service

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana, azure-bot-service

I am trying to enable Cortana channel to my Azure Bot Service. I am getting below message-

[image]

The bot was created by my official MSA ID under a subscription. I checked the publish profile and it seems the username and password is different and probably auto generated when I created the bot in Azure. Do I need to change the publish profile to use my official ID and password? In that case my credentials will be visible to anyone who is using the app in Azure portal.

Also my app seems to be registered on the bot framework portal-

[image]

However while navigating to-

https://dev.botframework.com/bots/channels?id=mybotid&channelId=cortana

I see the same message saying Cortana channel cannot be added.

Few observations-

- Unable to edit the app ID field
- Anyone can access the link- https://dev.botframework.com/bots/settings?id=mybotid even if the ownership is only having my email ID

Any help on this?

Comment: don't change the Id or password in the publish profile. These are generated when the bot is first created. Also, when you created the bot it was also automatically registered. You can ignore the option under 'Configuration' in your attached image. No one should be able to access your bot in Azure or on dev.botframework.com unless they your login credentials. These aren't public access points, hence, the use of channels to allow customers to reach your bot.

Comment: What SDK are you using?

Comment: @StevenKanberg I am using the QnA maker service. I created it using Web App bot on Azure and used the QnA template.

Comment: are  you still experiencing problems with enabling Cortana?

Comment: @StevenKanberg Yes. However I am now creating the Bot using custom coding (not through Azure). I will deploy it to Azure once my development is done and then try enabling Cortana channel.